# Checking strings as valid integers

Tags: java

i wan to split a string and then check if every part that i splitted is a number or an identifier this is what i did so far :)

```
public class splitest {


public void splitfunc() {


    String str = "A:25";
    String[] temp = null;
    temp = str.split(":");

    run(temp);
}

public void run(String[] s) {


    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

        if (s[i].equals(" ")) {   // <<<   checks if the splitted string is a digit ot not??

            System.out.println(s[i]+"  is a number");

            } else

                System.out.println(s[i]+"  is an Identfier");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    splitest ss = new splitest();
    ss.splitfunc();
}
  }
```

is there a way to convert the string into a digit then check or something?

the output should be like this:
this is an identifier
this is a number

Comment: You could use a regex, or try parsing it, or using valueOf. Do you know any of the Java APIs for strings or numbers or regexes? There are a lot of ways of going about this, and it's trivially searchable.

Comment: I'd go the regex route, where `^\d+$` means the string holds one or more digits exclusively.

Answer (score 3):

```
public boolean isInteger( String input )  
{  
   try  
   {  
      Integer.parseInt( input );  
      return true;  
   }  
   catch( Exception e )  
   {  
      return false;  
   }  
}  


String[] tokens = s.split("\s+");
for (String token : tokens) {
  if (isInteger(token)) {
    System.out.println(token + " is a number");
  } else {
    System.out.println(token + " is an identifier");
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) I would argue the regex is probably a "better" approach, 2) it's probably better practice to catch "NumberFormatException" instead of a blanket "Exception"

Comment: sorry, the first have was copied from the net and my C++ habits start to show